# Advice if safe from mail header injection PHP

Tags: email, php, injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP mail() Header Injection Prevention](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1108/php-mail-header-injection-prevention)

Since I only started learning about header injection in the PHP mail() function, am uncertain if the form/code below is vulnerable to attack and I am asking for advice.

I have been slowly building this over a long period of time, and would not be a very "Happy Camper" if subjected to attacks.

**Integrated PHP and submission form**

```
<?php

$target_site = 'http://www.somewhere.xxx/some_folder/try_to_access.php';

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && preg_match("/".preg_quote($target_site,"/")."/i",$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {


$file = "good_emails.txt";

$lines = count(file($file));


if ($lines > 100) {


header("Location: not_available_to_submit.php");

}

else {


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
$hasError = true;
} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$",   trim($_POST['email']))) {
$hasError = true;

echo "<font color=\"#CC3300\"><b>ERROR! Please enter a valid E-mail address.</b></font>";

} 

else {


if(trim($_POST['accept_terms']) == '') {
$hasError = true;

echo "<font color=\"#CC3300\"><b>ERROR! Please accept the terms and conditions.</b></font>";


} else {

$accept_terms = trim($_POST['accept_terms']);

}

$email = trim($_POST['email']);


}


if(!isset($hasError)) {

include 'form_validater.php';

}
}

}


}

else {


header("Location: improper_referer.php");

}


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Enter your E-mail address.</h2>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<input type="checkbox" name="accept_terms" value="accepted-terms" id="accept_terms" />
<i>Check the box if you accept the terms and conditions.</i>

<br><br>

<input type="text" size="35" name="email"> 
<input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
<br>
<b><u>Privacy policy:</u></b>
<br>
Email remains safe and not resold. You will receive an E-mail shortly after your submission, in order to <b>confirm.</b>

</body>
</html>
```

**And my form validating script - form_validater.php**

```
<?php

$emails = file_get_contents("good_emails.txt");

$email = $_POST['email'];

if ( preg_match( "/(?:^|\W){$email}(?:\W|$)/", $emails ) ) {


header('Location: exists_sorry.php');

}

else {

header('Location: thank_you.php');

$server_address = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$port_used = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


$today = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("y"));

$today2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() );


$currenttime = date('h:i:s:u');
list($hrs,$mins,$secs,$msecs) = split(':',$currenttime);


$email = $_POST['email'];

$to = "me@somewhere.com";
$subject = "New Email Address sent";
$headers = "From: $email\n";

$message = "A visitor to your site has sent the following email address to be added.\n
Email Address: $email

Used on Date: $today2

IP Address: $ip_address
Server address: $server_address
Port used: $port_used";

$user = "$email";

$usersubject = "Please confirm your email.";

$userheaders = "From: ".$_POST['email'];

$hash = hash('sha256', "mysalt".$email."addingmoresalt");


$usermessage = "Please click the link below to confirm your E-mail address: \n\nhttp://www.somewhere.xxx/confirm.php?email=".urlencode($email)."&hasher=$hash
\n
If you feel that you did not authorize this, simply ignore this message.";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);

$f = fopen('tmp_emails.txt', 'a+');

fwrite($f, $email." ");

fwrite($f, "Used on ".date("m/d/Y", $today). (" $hrs:$mins:$secs")." ");

fwrite($f, "IP address: ".$ip_address."\n");

fclose($f);


}

?>
```

Comment: Yes its unsafe, `$userheaders = "From: ".$_POST['email'];
` and eregi is DEPRECATED you should use `filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Comment: There are a number of PHP classes that provide injection protection for you.  I'd strongly suggest using one of those.  [A few are listed at the bottom of this page](http://www.securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection#Using_php_mail.28.29_function).

Comment: Skip using mail() and switch to PHPMailer or Swiftmailer, and your worries will be over.

Comment: @MarcB I searched for PHPMailer and found multiple versions of it. Do you have a specific link by chance?

Comment: I have done some research using `email1@somesite.com%0ACc:email2@othersite.com%0ABcc:email3@yetanother.com` as an example and the form is ok. Is there another test I could do myself, or should I not ask?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone What would you suggest I replace `$userheaders = "From: ".$_POST['email'];` with? And how do I incorporate `filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`? I'm confused.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Comment: (and I only mention the one from Security.SE)

Answer (score 3):

The `mail()` function uses an `additional_headers` parameter, which could be used to set other headers. You just have to separate them by a newline character.

Here is what you have to check:
Let's say, that you  have got an input which allows you to type `To:` e-mail. You type there eg. `mymail@stackexchange.com` and the e-mail is sent to that address. Try to inject another header, let's say `Bcc:`:

- *mymail@stackexchange.com**%0a**Bcc:anothermail@stackexchange.com*
- *mymail@stackexchange.com**%0d%0a**Bcc:anothermail@stackexchange.com*

You shoudn't forget to check if you code isn't vulnerable to SMTP Injection. Let's say that your script generate SMTP commands:

`MAIL FROM: first_email@stackexchange.com

RCPT TO: second_email@stackexchange.com

DATA

From: first_email@stackexchange.com

To: second_email@stackexchange.com

Subject: Important e-mail

text



.`

This commands could be generated by request: `?from=first_email@stackexchange.com&Subject=Important+e-mail&message=text`.

However you could try to inject another commands into Subject parameter as follows: `?from=first_email@stackexchange.com&Subject=Important+e-mail%0d%0a%2e%0d%0aMAIL+FROM:+attacker@stackexchange.com%0d%0aRCPT+TO:+victim@stackexchange.com%0d%0aDATA%0d%0aFrom:+attacker@stackexchange.com%0d%0aTo:+victim@stackexchange.com%0d%0aSubject:+Bum%0d%0ainjected%0d%0a%2e%0d%0a&message=text`
If your webapp is vulnerable, then it'll generate two different e-mail messages:

`MAIL FROM: first_email@stackexchange.com

RCPT TO: second_email@stackexchange.com

DATA

From: first_email@stackexchange.com

To: second_email@stackexchange.com

Subject: Important e-mail

text



. 

MAIL FROM: attacker@stackexchange.com

RCPT TO: victim@stackexchange.com

DATA

From: attacker@stackexchange.com

To: victim@stackexchange.com

Subject: Bum

injected



.`

Comment: How `Subject=Important%0d%0a%2e%0d%0a` turns into `Subject: Important e-mail
text

.`?

Comment: Thanks. It's corrected now. It should have been: `subject=Important+email` and `message=text`.